# apply condition if val for continuous minutes

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have this data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dates <- c("01/01/18 1:00:00 PM" ,"01/01/18 1:01:00 PM",
           "01/01/18 1:02:00 PM" ,"01/01/18 1:03:00 PM",
           "01/01/18 1:04:00 PM" ,"01/01/18 1:05:00 PM",
           "01/01/18 1:06:00 PM" ,"01/01/18 1:07:00 PM",
           "01/01/18 1:08:00 PM" ,"01/01/18 1:09:00 PM",
           "01/01/18 1:10:00 PM" ,"01/01/18 1:11:00 PM")

vals <- c(1, 2, 3, 3, 15, 16, 17, 18, 1, 2, 1, 22)

datfr <- data.frame(dates, vals)

datfr$dates <- dmy_hms(datfr$dates)
```

I want to apply a condition:

`if the val is < 4 for 2 continuous minutes period then true`

I tried :

```
datfr$gr <- datfr %>%
       group_by(by2min = cut(dates, "2 min")) %>%
       summarise(cond = (vals < 4))
```

but it gives me:

`column cond must be length 1 not 2`

and I am not sure for the approach.

So, my expected output:

```
dates                   vals     cond

1 2018-01-01 13:00:00     1      
2 2018-01-01 13:01:00     2      
3 2018-01-01 13:02:00     3      TRUE
4 2018-01-01 13:03:00     3     
5 2018-01-01 13:04:00    15      FALSE
6 2018-01-01 13:05:00    16     
7 2018-01-01 13:06:00    17      FALSE
8 2018-01-01 13:07:00    18      
9 2018-01-01 13:08:00     1      FALSE
10 2018-01-01 13:09:00    2      
11 2018-01-01 13:10:00    1      TRUE
12 2018-01-01 13:11:00   22
```

Hence, if the for 2 continuous minutes the val is < 4 then true.

Comment: I'd start from `summarise(cond = all(vals < 4))` adjusting the code according to the desired output. plus, your `cut` do not cut data into 2min intervals, at least not the way you show in your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your data is in a format where the time diffs are 1 minute between row entries

```
datfr$cond<-
zoo::rollapply(data = datfr$vals, width = 3, FUN = function(x) { if (all(x < 4)) return(TRUE) else return(FALSE) }, align = "right", fill = FALSE)
```

result:

```
#                 dates vals  cond
#1  2018-01-01 13:00:00    1 FALSE
#2  2018-01-01 13:01:00    2 FALSE
#3  2018-01-01 13:02:00    3  TRUE
#4  2018-01-01 13:03:00    3  TRUE
#5  2018-01-01 13:04:00   15 FALSE
#6  2018-01-01 13:05:00   16 FALSE
#7  2018-01-01 13:06:00   17 FALSE
#8  2018-01-01 13:07:00   18 FALSE
#9  2018-01-01 13:08:00    1 FALSE
#10 2018-01-01 13:09:00    2 FALSE
#11 2018-01-01 13:10:00    1  TRUE
#12 2018-01-01 13:11:00   22 FALSE
```

Comment: So, if I want to apply the condition by every 120 minutes, I would use `rollaply(datfr$vals, width = 120)` or `width = 121` ?

Comment: not entirely sure what you want. Make an easy example for yourself with maybe window of 10 and see what you need. 10 or 11. This logic will transfer to 120.

Comment: I mean, if I had many rows of data and wanted to apply the condition for every 120 continuous minutes instead of 2 minutes.

Comment: for 2 minutes I needed to use 3 so I would assume for 120 i need a width of 121

Answer (score 1):

I've tried just to reproduce your desired output as close as it possible. I assume that empty elements of `cond` are `NA`s. In case if `cond` is a `character` variable, and empty elements represent `\s` it's easy to adjust the output by adding additional `mutate(cond = coalesce(as.character(cond), ""))`. I failed with conversion of the last value into `\s/NA`.

```
#library(tidyverse)

datfr %>%
  arrange(dates) %>%
  group_by(by2min = lag(cut(c(min(dates), dates), "2 min"))[-1]) %>%
  mutate(dates = max(dates)) %>%
  group_by(dates) %>%
  summarise(cond = all(vals < 4), vals = last(vals)) %>%
  right_join(datfr, by = c('dates', 'vals')) %>%
  select(dates, vals, cond)

# # A tibble: 12 x 3
#   dates                vals cond 
#   <dttm>              <dbl> <lgl>
# 1 2018-01-01 13:00:00     1 NA   
# 2 2018-01-01 13:01:00     2 NA   
# 3 2018-01-01 13:02:00     3 TRUE 
# 4 2018-01-01 13:03:00     3 NA   
# 5 2018-01-01 13:04:00    15 FALSE
# 6 2018-01-01 13:05:00    16 NA   
# 7 2018-01-01 13:06:00    17 FALSE
# 8 2018-01-01 13:07:00    18 NA   
# 9 2018-01-01 13:08:00     1 FALSE
#10 2018-01-01 13:09:00     2 NA   
#11 2018-01-01 13:10:00     1 TRUE 
#12 2018-01-01 13:11:00    22 FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks!Nice solution.I prefer the rollapply though.(upv)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `rollapply`?

```
zoo::rollapply(datfr$vals, 3, by = 1, function(x) sum(x<4) == 2)
```

Edit: simplified function

Comment: your function can be simplified to: `function(x) length(x[x<4]) == 2)` or even`function(x) sum(x<4) == 2`

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that it returns 10 rows and the data has 12, so I am receiving an error.